# How to overcome the odd memory allocation of 1st element of Linked List in an input function?

Tags: c, memory-management, linked-list

The requirement is an `input` function that returns a `Node*` to the root of a linked list that `input` creates from the user's input.
Like:

```
Node *input()
{
     Node *root; //not yet allocated
     while(1)
     {    
           //take in numbers from the user and correspondingly add them 
           //to the linked list and quit when anything else is entered

           if(input character is a number)
           {
                //allocate memory to a fresh pointer and push the number to it
                //and add this new Node to the LL
           }
     }
     return root;
}
```

**->**  There is the solution of pre-allocating memory to `root` and pushing the 1st number to it before the while loop body. But here, if the user won't enter anything, that must deleted right away.

**->** Also, there is a possible way of checking if root is NULL in the while loop, and if it is, allocating memory , so that it happens only once.

But I would like to know if there is a solution that will eliminate that odd situation arising from the root of the LL.

**->** Maybe I could keep a dummy node at the 1st that doesn't hold any values.

But apart from that?
If there is a better method of doing the whole thing, please suggest it.

Comment: Are you adding to the head of the list?

Comment: There is no list before a call to input(). I make a call to input() from the main function and store the newly created root, in a `Node*` and use it in the main function.

Comment: I understand that. But as you build the list, are you simply adding new items to the head of the list (i.e. prepending) or doing something more complicated?

Comment: Then: if you only input one value,why the loop?

Comment: @Mat , In the input() function , as I build the list, new elements taken from the user are added along the head, like in a linked list. New nodes are added to the end of the list "so-far". I'm simply trying to create an abstraction, that will give a freshly created Linked List taken from the user. I'm sorry if I didn't understand you completely. Is this what you ask?

Comment: @wildplasser, not just one element. How many ever the user wants to enter.

Comment: Well, in that case you'll have to append the new item to the linked list, either at the beginning or at the end. Don't forget to initialise the `root` pointer to NULL!

Comment: @learner the question would have been clearer had you included whether you are dealing with a single or double linked list, and in which order the elements from the input should occur in the result list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
struct Node* root = 0; // don't forget to initialize

while (...) {
  if (...) {
    struct Node * item = ... ;  // allocate
    item->data = ...;
    item->next = root;
    root = item;
  }
}

return root;
```

And you're done, no special case required for the first element. The end of list is indicated by a null `next` pointer.

If you want the list to be in insertion order, without traversing the whole list each time, you could:

```
struct Node* root = 0; // don't forget to initialize
struct Node* tail = 0;

while (...) {
  if (...) {
    struct Node * item = ... ;  // allocate
    item->data = ...;
    item->next = 0;

    if (tail)
      tail->next = item;
    tail = item;

    if (!root)
      root = item;
  }
}

return root;
```

No special-case allocation, but special-case assignments.

Comment: this will reverse the list (not saying it's bad, but perhaps not what the OP wants)

Comment: This will make a reversed linked list.

Comment: @learner: if you can understand that, you could write the code yourself.

Comment: @learner: yes, that's what I thought you were doing based on your comments, but now I read them again I'm confused.

Comment: This would be fine, though a normal linked list would have been better. There seems to be no solution to it apart from the dummy node method.

Comment: @Mat, I'm no sure how that was conveyed from my comments :) . Anyway, all I wanted was a function that will ask the user for any number of inputs and push them in a new linked list and return the root of it.(without the special case for the root).

Comment: @learner: I just provided another version of this with in-order list. The special-casing isn't too bad (IMO).

Comment: @mat, yes this is way better.

Answer (score 1):

None of the solutions seems complex to be, but using a dummy node you'll have a quite clean code:

```
Node root; //stored on the stack
root->next = NULL;

//...

return root->next;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version that avoids special cases, it uses a pointer-to-pointer:

```
struct list {
        struct list *next;
        int val;
        };

struct list *input(void)
{
struct list *ret=NULL, **tail;
char buff[100];

for (tail= &ret; fgets(buff, sizeof buff, stdin);       ) {
        int val;
        if ( sscanf(buff,"%d", &val) < 1) continue;
        *tail = malloc (sizeof **tail);
        (*tail)->next = NULL;
        (*tail)->val = val;
        tail = &(*tail)->next;
        }
return ret;
}
```